# Laravel mail sending is not working in the cloud instance

Tags: php, laravel, email, laravel-5

I have a laravel 5.2 application. I have configured gmail smtp server in my application and it works fine in my local machine.

After I deployed the application to the cloud instance it gives

> Expected response code 250 but got code "535", with message "535-5.7.8
>   Username and Password not accepted

These are configuration details in my .env file.

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp 
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com 
MAIL_PORT=465 
MAIL_USERNAME=mailID 
MAIL_PASSWORD="mailPassword" 
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
```

Please give me a help to avoid this issue. I thought that mail port is blocked, but it's not and I'm getting a credentials issue.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25193467/gmail-locks-account-when-sending-mail-via-laravel

Comment: @Naincy this is a different issue for two reasons. I have already enabled the ''less secure apps" and this is working fine in my local machine